# Best Way to Support Increment and Decrement in Template Class

Tags: java, generics

I would like to create a template function that relies on a generic type's ability to support `++` and `--`.  As we know, Java does **not** support operator overloading so apparently I need to define an interface that requires an `increment()` and a `decrement()` function:

```
public interface Quantized<E> extends Comparable<E> {
  public <E extends Quantized> E increment();
  public <E extends Quantized> E decrement();
}

public class Sequencer<E extends Quantized>{
  private E value;

  public <E extends Quantized> E doSometingWithSequence(){
    ...
    E rv = value.increment();
    return rv;
  }
}
```

If I want the template to support any class then even knowing of an interface that says that `++` and `--` are supported would not be enough as Java does not allow us to implement operators for classes.  *However, it would be nice to allow the template function to support types such as Integer without the need for a wrapper class to implement the interface`Quantized`.*

Is there a way around defining a new interface (other than defining an abstract class)?

Comment: Handling both primatives and objects the same way without wrappers is tricky. Primatives are built for speed, not for conforming with the rest of java

Comment: You could write a wrapper for just [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html).

Comment: if you want see http://amelentev.github.io/java-oo/ for operator overloading in java

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am considering this option.  The only problem is that I may need to do some bounds checking during increment and decrement, thought i suppose Number throws when it is out of bounds.

Comment: @vandale Very cool. This is the first time I have heard of Java-OO.  i am having a look right now.

Answer (score 0):

There are no another variant if you need generics. It's the main purpose of generic - check class has methods in compilation time. But you can write this functionality with reflection. Check if the object has increment method in runtime and invoke it.